# Enhanced ecommerce & Bundle products

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

how would you implement BUNDLE product? I can't find any directions or recommendations.

I mean we have product page selling walking tours. It consists of adult ticket (required, main one) and child ticket. Something like this:

[image]

I see 2 options:

1st) to treat them as separate products and give them separate IDs.

Downside - now we will have separate impressions, etc. But they are not really separate products.

2nd) to treat it as 1 product(one ID), and create custom dimensions.

I like this approach better, but not sure what custom dimensions to use, and than how to do "add to cart".

Comment: If I face anything like this, i would create 1 product and 2 variants (not custom dimensions), you can create variants of products.

Comment: @user3550203, thank you! will look into that.